# deploying spfx .sppkg package in sharepoint 2019 doesn't work but it work fine using debugging url

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I'm troubling with issues when trying to deploy Spfx command Set extension using sppkg in Sharepoint Server 2019

It work fine using debug url after running `gulp serve`

but when i moved to deploy it using sppkg package it doesn't worked like using debug url

I have added sharepoint app successfully like below
[image: sharepoint app added successfully]
but no command set are available
then i found no json file and manifest.js are loaded in page
i have checked my package-solution.json and `"includeClientSideAssets": true` to include all app assets in sppkg file like mentioned in officiel sharepoint framework support doc
[sharepoint framework 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2019-support) support and [sharepoint framework 2016 support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-2016-support)

Then i passed to include dependencies using cdn in ***write-manifests.json*** config file

I have created library to host assets files and i have also used Style library and used their url in manifest config, both of them didn't work

then i tried to host dependencies in local IIS without result

at the end i have created azure storage and azure cdn ( i kept this solution at the end juste for testing) and here the strange i did not find external hosting from azure in my sharepoint site
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem,
my problem was not related to CDN, i have just left cdn path in  ***write-manifests.json*** empty

then i found that the id in `pageCommandSetCommandSet.manifest.json` was not the same for `ClientSideComponentId` in `elements.xml`

As mentioned in officiel doc  [Build your first ListView Command Set extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)

> Note the following XML structure in elements.xml. The
> ClientSideComponentId property has been updated to the unique ID of
> your ListView Command Set available in the
> ./src/extensions/helloWorld/HelloWorldCommandSet.manifest.json file.

Comment: Quick question: did you use YeoMan to create the project scaffolding?

Comment: Yes of course i use yeoman generator v 3.1.1 to create my project
But i created an extension inside an other project